# Org-mode agenda clocktable report properties columns broken?

Tags: org-mode

I'm using a customized clockreport as shown below, it worked for over a year but now the selected properties column values are not shown in the agenda clockreport anymore. Do I need to change something? The properties columns are showing but not the values of them. Everything else in the table looks normal.

```
(setq org-agenda-clockreport-parameter-plist (quote
 (:lang "de" :maxlevel 6 :fileskip0 t
 :properties ("Auftragsnummer" "Leistungsart" "Abgemeldet")
 :indent t :narrow 80!)))
```

Org mode Example

```
** [[./2017/XXXXXXXXXXXX_123456789]] :SOMETAG:SOMETAG:SOMETAG:SOMETAG:
:PROPERTIES:
:Auftragsnummer: 123456789
:END:
*** Tätigkeiten
**** ERLEDIGT Done Something
:PROPERTIES:
:Abgemeldet: Ja
:Leistungsart: ABCDE01
:END:
CLOCK: [2017-05-20 Sa 10:00]--[2017-05-20 Sa 11:00] =>  1:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in 9.0.7. Upgrade to 9.0.8 fixed it.